# Reversing arrays in 2D arrays in Python

Tags: python, list, 2d, reverse

I have a question wether it is possible to reverse certain arrays in my 2D array.
For example

```
a=[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]] 
a[1:3].reverse()
print(a)
```

would output:

```
[1,2],[5,6],[3,4]
```

I hope you can help :)

Answer (score 2):

```
a = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
a = a[:1] + list(reversed(a[1:3]))
print(a)
```

You could also use pure slicing, but imo the previous version is more readable:

```
a = a[:1] + a[:-3:-1]
```

Comment: to add explanation, `a[1:3]` creates a new list and because `.reverse` is an *in-place* method - `a` is not affected

Answer (score 0):

Your code is actually reversing a copy, and not changing the underlying array.

I'd do this:

```
a[1:3] = reversed(a[1:3])
```

It takes a reversed copy of the elements from 1 to three and puts them into their initial locations.